# extract date from datatime in php or Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, datetime, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have a table in my cakephp which have a field name **datetime** and datatype is **datetime**
storing in this format

```
 2013-06-18 00:00:00
```

I need to extract the date part of the value not the time ..

i extract time like this

```
        $dateTime = $recentCall['Calllog']['dateTime'];
    $time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($datetime));
```

now i want to extract the date part.which i dont know how can i do this .. i have done some research but nothing works out for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't exactly a CakePHP answer, but a PHP one.

```
$dateTime  = $recentCall['Calllog']['dateTime'];
$timestamp = strtotime($dateTime);
$date      = date('Y-m-d' , $timestamp);
$time      = date('H:i:s' , $timestamp);
```

If you want to do somethink more Cakeish and use the CakePHP wrapper, should be:

```
$dateTime  = $recentCall['Calllog']['dateTime'];
$timestamp = CakeTime::fromString($dateTime);
$date      = CakeTime::format($dateTime, 'Y-m-d');
$time      = CakeTime::format($dateTime, 'H:i:s');
```

I hope my answer is clear.
Ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html

Comment: well thankyou for your answer i tried both of your solutions php and cakephp .. the php one works but Cakephp doesn't printing the date, instead of it is printing just this ..'Y-m-d'

Comment: Stick to the PHP version, using `CakeTime` doesn't provide any advantages in your case. `CakeTime` is useful for Date Objects, but has been know to have some bugs (it's a smaller open-source project than PHP, so you can't expect the same level of robustness).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Y-m-d` as first parameter in `date` to extract date.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($datetime));
```